# PHP string how to extract part after pattem to a separate variable

Tags: php, regex, strpos

I have a string that collects two pieces of information.  Everything before the slash is a search variable, and everything after is the page number.

Assume the following:

`$search = "classic rock/8"`

should be $searchvalue[0]='classic $searchvalue[1]='rock' $searchvalue[x]= etc...
and then $page=8

I tried a few approaches, the last one is to do three passes by first removing everything after the slash.

`$search=substr($search, 0, strpos($search, '/'));`

and then separate the $search values into an array.
and then go back (a 3rd time!) and get the page variable by deleting everything before the slash.

I know this is highly inefficient.  Is there a way to do these actions in one pass?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe simply split on spaces, then do a regex on the last indexed variable to get the number.

Answer (score 3):

You can explode that string **twice** and get the same results!

```
$res = explode("/", $search); 
$page = $res[1]; //This is the page

$searchValues = explode(" ", $res[0]); //These are the results
```

Comment: Yes, 2x is better than 3x, but I was hoping to do it in one pass.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strrpos`:

```
$search = 'classic rock/8';
$page = substr($search, strrpos($search, '/')+1); // 8
```

Comment: This would be good for a one digit page variable.  what if it's "jazz/14" ?  I don't know how many pages there are for each subject.

Answer (score 0):

In response to getting it in one pass, you can use the preg match all function or
you can use the preg split function.

Either way has its drawbacks, but so does explode and strrpos or anything else.

A lot of people don't realize they can use preg split in a much more detailed way
to precisely carve up a string. This can be done by defining splits in detail to include captures. Its a little different this way, but has big power if you learn how to do it.

Regex:

```
  #  ([^\s\/]+)(?:\s+|$)|\/+\s*(\d+)[\s\/]*$|\/.*$

                       # Delim-1
     ( [^\s\/]+ )      # (1), A group of not whitespace nor forward slash
     (?: \s+ | $ )     # folowed by whitespace or EOL

                       # Delim-2
  |  \/+ \s*           # Forward slashes folowed by whitespaces
     ( \d+ )           # (2), folowed by a group of digits
     [\s\/]* $         # followed by whitespaces or slashes until EOL

                       # Delim-3
  |  \/ .* $           # Forward slash folowed by anything until EOL
```

PHP code:

```
 <?php
 $keywords = preg_split
     ( 
         "/([^\s\/]+)(?:\s+|$)|\/+\s*(\d+)[\s\/]*$|\/.*$/",
         "classic rock/8",
         -1,
         PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE 
     );
 print_r($keywords);
 ?> 

 Result:
 Array
 (
     [0] => classic
     [1] => rock
     [2] => 8
 )
```